# ispell personal dictionary for multiple languages

Tags: ispell, hunspell

I use hunspell for spellchecking.  When I switch dictionaries (e.g., from en_US to hu_HU), I cannot save personal words to my personal dictionary.  Emacs complains that

> ispell-init-process: Error: Expected language "hu" but got "en".

I assume that's because the value of `ispell-personal-dictionary` is ~/.aspell.en.pws, and the first line of that file is `personal_ws-1.1 en 46`.  Maybe I should not use aspell's personal dictionary for hunspell, but when I set `ispell-personal-dictionary` to a new (empty) file, the message I get

> ispell-init-process: Error: The file "[filename]" is not in the proper format.

(Hunspell personal dictionaries are supposed to be simple word lists, according to the [man page](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/4-hunspell/).)

1. How can I set up separate personal word lists for different languages?
2. What is the format for a hunspell personal dictionary?

(+1. Incidentally, to make sure I run hunspell, I added `ispell-program-name (executable-find "hunspell")` to my .emacs, which resulted in

> split-string: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil

hunspell does run, but only if `ispell-program-name` is not set.)

Comment: Good question but can't help you sorry. I do have `'(ispell-program-name "/usr/bin/hunspell")` in my custom-set-variables which works for setting hunspell as default.